# What is the expected output of pgr_lineGraph()?

Tags: postgis, pgrouting

I am trying to use `pgr_lineGraph()` to generate some edge-based catchments from a street network model. My expectation is that `pgr_lineGraph()` should create a node for every edge in the original graph and then create an edge between the new nodes if their corresponding edges meet at a node in the original graph.

[image: small network extract]

I have a small extract of my original larger network (shown above) for which I believe I have correctly generated the topology.

| id | geom | source | target | cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5974 | "xxxx" | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 5976 | "xxxx" | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 5977 | "xxxx" | 2 | 4 | 1 |
| 5975 | "xxxx" | 5 | 3 | 1 |
| 5987 | "xxxx" | 3 | 6 | 1 |

My expectation is that when I run

```
SELECT * FROM pgr_lineGraph(
    'SELECT id, source, target, cost FROM schema.network', directed := FALSE
);
```

I should get a new graph similar to:

| source | target |
| --- | --- |
| 5974 | 5977 |
| 5974 | 5976 |
| 5976 | 5977 |
| 5976 | 5987 |
| 5976 | 5975 |
| 5975 | 5987 |

But I don't get that, I only get four edges.

| seq | source | target | cost | reverse_cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5974 | 5977 | 1 | -1 |
| 2 | 5975 | 5976 | 1 | -1 |
| 3 | 5975 | 5987 | 1 | -1 |
| 4 | 5976 | 5977 | 1 | -1 |

Am I doing something wrong or is this the expected output from `pgr_lineGraph()`?

I am using pgr_version 3.0.0-rc1 on postgis_version 3.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, it is missing 2 edges

```
create table lnedges(                                                                                                   
id INTEGER,                                                                                                             
source INTEGER,                                                                                                         
target INTEGER,                                                                                                         
cost INTEGER);                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                        
INSERT INTO lnedges (id, source, target, cost)                                                                          
VALUES (                                                                                                                
(5974, 1, 2, 1),                                                                                                        
(5976, 3, 2, 1),                                                                                                        
(5977, 2, 4, 1),                                                                                                        
(5975, 5, 3, 1),                                                                                                        
(5987, 3, 6, 1));

SELECT * FROM pgr_lineGraph(
 'SELECT id, source, target, cost FROM lnedges', directed := FALSE);
 seq | source | target | cost | reverse_cost 
-----+--------+--------+------+--------------
   1 |   5974 |   5977 |    1 |           -1
   2 |   5975 |   5976 |    1 |           -1
   3 |   5975 |   5987 |    1 |           -1
   4 |   5976 |   5977 |    1 |           -1
(4 rows)
```

Expected result (ignoring the seq value)

```
 seq | source | target | cost | reverse_cost 
-----+--------+--------+------+--------------
   1 |   5974 |   5977 |    1 |           -1
   2 |   5975 |   5976 |    1 |           -1
   3 |   5975 |   5987 |    1 |           -1
   4 |   5976 |   5977 |    1 |           -1
   x |   5976 |   5987 |    1 |           -1
   x |   5974 |   5976 |    1 |           -1
```

The function is still experimental.
I added the problem to the [issue 2564](https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/issues/2564) of pgRouting.

Regards
Vicky Vergara
PSC of pgRouting

Comment: Hi Vicky, thanks for confirming the problem and thanks for making it an issue as well.